# How to format an associative array to columns and rows in plain text?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array which looks like:

```
Array (
 [class_name] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
 [zone1_price] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => s )
 [zone2_price] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => t )
 [zone3_price] => Array ( [0] => c [1] => u )
 [zone4_price] => Array ( [0] => d [1] => v )
)
```

I want the data to be in the following format:

```
| Class Name | Zone 1 | Zone 2 | Zone 3 | Zone 4 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1          |  a     |   b    |   c    |   d    |
```

I tried a single foreach but couldn't get it to work, I am thinking it's going to need 2 or more foreach's but I am struggling to put the right code together.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the single foreach loop you tried? When asking questions on SO it is useful to show your code so that we can see where you are going wrong. Do you need the items in element [1] as well or only the items in element [0]?

Comment: it will be multiple so could be upto 30 rows so needs to loop through

Comment: 1. Don't forget to give a name to your array. 2. The keys must be quoted: `'class_name'`, `'zone1_price'`, and so on. 3. The first line of your output doesn't correspond exactly to given keys, try to be more accurate in the way you explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, but the values are not centred :

```
$array = [
 'class_name' => Array ('1', '2' ),
 'zone1_price' => Array ('a', 's' ),
 'zone2_price' => Array ('b', 't' ),
 'zone3_price' => Array ('c', 'u' ),
 'zone4_price' => Array ('d', 'v' ),
];
echo display_table($array,true);


function display_table($array, $forweb = true) {
    $string = "" ;
    $nl = $forweb ? "<br>" : "\n" ;

    $max=0;
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
        $max = max($max,strlen($k));
        $max = max($max,count($value));
    }
    $max+=2;

    if ($forweb) $string .= "<pre>";
    $string .= "| " ;
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
        $string .= sprintf("%{$max}s",$k." ")."|";
    }
    $string .= $nl;
    $string .= "+" . str_repeat("-", ($max+1)*count($array)) . "+" ;
    $string .= $nl;
    for ($i=0;$i<count(reset($array));$i++){
        $string .= "| " ;
        foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
            $string .= sprintf("%{$max}s",$value[$i]." ")."|";
        }
        $string .= $nl;
    }
    if ($forweb) $string .= "</pre>";
    return $string ;
}
```

Outputs:

```
|   class_name | zone1_price | zone2_price | zone3_price | zone4_price |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            1 |           a |           b |           c |           d |
|            2 |           s |           t |           u |           v |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've clearly understood your request, but it seems to me you're searching for something like this

```
$arr = array (
 'class_name' => array (1,2), 
 'zone1_price' => array ('a','s' ),
 'zone2_price' => array ('b', 't' ),
 'zone3_price' => array ('c', 'u' ),
 'zone4_price' => array ('d', 'v' )
);

$newarray = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $newarray[$key] = $val[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I that's all there is to it, then just `implode` the keys of the main array and then `implode` key 0 from the sub-arrays:

```
echo implode('|', array_keys($array);
echo '<br>';
echo implode('|', array_column($array, 0);
```